# how to modify certain phrases in a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:

i am trying to add certian acronyms to any random string that is entered by the user, for example like:

input (by the user):

'by the way i called them and they were not having any of it laugh out loud!'

output(by the program):

'btw i called them and they were not having any of it lol!

WHAT I TRIED TO DO:

i tried the for loop and the split() function (for e in x.split(',')) where x is the string entered by the user. However the result of the input was the same as the output unless if the whole string was the phrase that is going to be the acronym, for example like:

input:

'by the way'

output:

'btw'

and does not work with...

input:

'by the way i called them and they were not having any of it laugh out loud!'

because the output will be the same:

output:

'by the way i called them and they were not having any of it laugh out loud!'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of abbreviations then you can just loop through every abbreviation and replace all instances in a string:

```
abbr = {
    "by the way": "btw",
    "laugh out loud": "lol"
}
string = "by the way I called them and they were not having any of it laugh out loud!"
for full, short in abbr.items():
    string = string.replace(full, short)
print(string)
```